# Function that takes in a block?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I need a special version of dispatch_after. I need it to pass a parameter to the anonymous function, and the anonymous function checks if the parameter and a class variable match before executing.

I already have it working like this:

```
  double delayInSeconds = 5;
    dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC);

    int mod = self.invalidationCount;

    dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
        if(mod == self.invalidationCount)
            [self doAction:speed accelTime:accel];
    });
```

However, this is dirty as is. I have to copy this chunk around everywhere I need it in my class.

Here is what I would like:

Something along the lines of:

```
double delayInSeconds = 5;
 dispatch_after_safe(delayInSeconds,self, ^(void){
                [self doAction:speed accelTime:accel];
        });
```

or if possible, in message form so I don't have to pass self, but thats no issue...

Essentially, dispatch_after_safe should do something like:

```
{
      dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC);

      int mod = parameterSelf.invalidationCount;

        dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
            if(mod == parameterSelf.invalidationCount)
                //execute the parameter block
        });
}
```

Essentially, I need a wrapper for what I am currently doing, but I'm new to objective C and I'm not quite sure syntactically how to do something like this.

The whole point of doing this is, the user can press Back which should halt any queued future events.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean something like this:

```
void dispatch_after_safe(NSTimeInterval delay, id pmself, dispatch_block_t block) {
    dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delay * NSEC_PER_SEC);
    int mod = pmself.invalidationCount;
    dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
        if (mod == pmself.invalidationCount) {
            block();
        }
    });
}
```

(I recommend replacing the type `id` with whatever class of object it is supposed to be used with.)